# Optimising pond volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to work out how to optomise a problem with multiple variables - namely optomising a pond to hold water with a known volume against some design goals.

My goal is to get some guidance on the maths so I can learn more about the methods used for optomisation problems such as these. I'm fifteen years past my undergrad maths courses - I don't know what this field of maths is called, so am struggling to find help on the web!

The initial (simple) case is as follows:

- pond shape is an inverted rectangular pyramidal frustum (I think thats the correct term)
- pond digs into the ground, and uses the material to build a wall around the pond
- wall has sides that are slopes into the pond, and away from the pond
- x & y are length of wall sides and are not equal
- angle of internal and external wall slopes are 1:3

Primary Goals

- pond will hold a volume of water (say) = 100,000m3
- minimise the internal (water contact) surface area of the pond
- volume of material dug out of the ground >= the volume of the embankment (minimise excessive material -> ie. as close to zero as possible)

Secondary Goals

- deeper pond is better than shallow (to minimise evaporation) (Ref: http://web.deu.edu.tr/atiksu/ana52/sta3-12.gif)
  [image: Example concept - Ref: http://web.deu.edu.tr/atiksu/ana52/sta3-12.gif]

Comment: I would recommend you to express you sentences in a more formal way, for example, I don't know what does it mean 1:3 for an angle.

Comment: Thanks for responding - sorry about the formality.  1:3 angle is shorthand for rise over run, so 1 measure of vertical for every three measures of horizontal - or ~18.43 degrees from horizontal